# SDWebImage library does not work with simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, libraries, sdwebimage

I am using `SDWebImage` library. It works fine when I am using iPhone but does not work when I compile with simulator. I get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SDWebImageManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in DetailViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SDWebImagePrefetcher", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

But it does not give any error when I compile while using iPhone device. I am using `.a` file.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get this error, the library wasn't compiled for the simulator (`i386`) architecture. This problem cannot be resolved.

You would need to get the source code an compile the lib for this architecture too. Or you might ask the author if he can compile a simulator-supported version for you.

There are possibilities to make a "fat binary" from a `armv7` library that supports `armv7s` as well. This is because the `armv7s` has the same instructions, and *extends* the `armv7`.

Since the `i386` has completely different instructions, there won't be a way to use a arm-only lib in the simulator.

**EDIT** See [this support matrix](http://iossupportmatrix.com) for more info

**EDIT II** If you compile the lib on your own, you have to include the intel architecture too. Since the simulator runs on the Mac (intel processor, not ARM) the correct architecture is `i386`. Thee see matrix mentioned above for more details.

Comment: I have compiled library using armv7, armv7s and arm64.

Comment: Yep. But not `i386`. `arm64` is for iPad and iPhone5. Since the simulator runs on your Mac, you need an intel architecture, not an ARM one. See my edit. Add `i386` to the architectures your building the lib for, this should do the trick.

Comment: When you compile for `armv7 armv7s arm64 i386`, what does the `file` command tell you, when you run it in terminal pointing to the binary?

Comment: It says compiled successfully.

Comment: Sure. But issue the terminal command after compilation to determine if the build was successful for all archs you wanted. Better try `lip -info your_library.a`, it's more reliable.

Comment: it is saying for this one now:x86_64

Comment: Okay. Try building it for devices first, then for simulator and then use the terminal to create a fat library from the two resulting binaries: `lipo -create libPhone.a libSimulator.a -output libUniversal.a` and use the universal variant

Comment: And read this tutorial, they tell you how it's done automatically http://blog.sigmapoint.pl/automatic-build-of-static-library-for-ios-for-many-architectures/

Comment: Great, goo I could help! Did you use the manual, or the automated solution?

Comment: I used terminal for the first time to compile library. and it worked